# How to be notified when a window created using window.open is closed?

Tags: javascript

I tried:

```
var sub_window = window.open(url);
sub_window.onunload = function(){
    console.log("sub window closed");
};
```

but it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work for remote urls, because you do not have permission to interact with those.

It will work just fine for local urls, but you need to give a delay, so that the event gets applied to the actual opened page.

```
var w = window.open(url);

setTimeout(function(){
    w.onunload = function(){alert('done');};
},1000);
```

---

**Update**

Answering to your comment,

The [same origin policy <sup>wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) does not allow this, but just for this case of subdomains you might be able to [override it <sup>wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Additional_document.domain_logic) by setting the `document.domain` to **`'xxx.com'`** (*if you have control of both pages*)

Comment: I open `www.xxx.com` from `aaa.xxx.com`, is that considered a local url or remote url?

Comment: @wong2, updated answer that explains the issue and offers a possible workaround..